# Chrome automation extension locked when running Selenium test case

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I'm facing a problem about running my test cases on Google Chrome. The warning is: Google Chrome automation extension locked. I am using Selenium web driver for automating my test cases and it is running on Firefox without any problem.

This message occurred on RIDE;

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open
pages   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243
(0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Windows NT 6.0
x86_64)

20151008 14:19:31.499 :  FAIL : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has
no attribute 'close'
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Update your ChromeDriver and use latest Chrome binary from below link:-

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Try this also:-

Set 'Turn off display after' in Windows Power Options to 'Never'.